# What are the speeds of the Eagle and Mark IX Hawks on Space: 1999?

Tags: space-1999

What are the speeds of the Eagles and Hawks spacecraft in Space:1999? I have some information on space: 1999 Wiki not sure how accurate that is. On the episode Wargames the speed was given "at V 14.2" Koening replies "nearly twice the speed of our Eagles." So what speed is V 14.2?

Comment: The Moonbase Alpha Technical Handbook gives the speed of an Eagle as 0.15 lightspeed. How this relates to "a speed of 7" (about half of 14.2), I don't know.

Comment: Is that handbook considered canon?

Comment: It was approved and authorised by Gerry Anderson productions, so it's probably as canon as you'll get. Space: 1999 was not terribly consistent on numbers in general though.

Answer (score 5):

In 1977 *Starlog* published the “[Moonbase Alpha Technical Notebook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000K11ROC)”. It came in a 3-ring binder, and claimed to be "the only authorized version approved by Gerry Anderson Productions and ITC Entertainment". This probably makes it as canonical as possible for anything that is not directly referenced in the episodes themselves.

The original notebook did not contain technical specifications of the Eagle and Hawk spacecraft, but these were published subsequently in *Starlog* so that enthusiasts could cut them out and clip them into the binder. The plans for the Eagle were published in *Starlog #7* (August 1977), and for the [Hawk](https://archive.org/details/starlog_magazine-032/page/n51/mode/2up) in *Starlog #32* (March 1980). I have not been able to find an online version of *Starlog #7*, but I believe the blueprints are the same as those given in the updated version of the Technical Notebook (the Technical Notebook Fan Edition) and the later  [Moonbase Alpha Technical Operation Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/191452215X), released in 2021.

[image: Technical specifications of the Eagle and Hawk spacecraft]

The numbers given are: the **Eagle's speed 0.15 c**, and the **Hawk's speed 0.22 c**. These numbers are also quoted by the [Space:1999 wiki](https://moonbasealpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eagle_Transporter).

As to the lines from *Wargames*:

> DAVID: "Alien ships approaching at speed fourteen point two."
>
> KOENIG: "That's nearly twice the speed of our Eagles."

I think we can only speculate. But out of interest, if we set the speed of light to be 50 in some set of units, then the speed of an Eagle would be 7.5 in those units. An alien ship moving at 14.2 would indeed have a speed nearly twice that of an Eagle. This is surely over-analysing it though.

Comment: If The Expanse series taught us anything, it's that some form of basic physics apply to space travel with rockets and those Eagles aren't accelerating (and decelerating) enough to reach .15 lightspeed. But any deep analysis of Space: 1999 would surely result in space madness...

Comment: The image you've put up states 0.22c for the Hawk, but you say 0.33c in the text - am I missing something?

Comment: @Michael My fat fingers...

Answer (score 0):

The Moon seemed to pass close to a star system with planets every week or every month of fictional time which elapsed on the Moon.

If the Moon was traveling at almost the speed of light, time dilation could make many years of travel between star systems seem like only days, weeks, or months on Moonbase Alpha.

If the Moon was travelling at almost the speed of light, the Eagles would need to decelerated from almost the speed of light to match velocities with a star system and land on a planet there.  Then they would have to take off and accelerate to almost the speed of light to get back to Moonbase Alpha.

So this line of deduction indicates that there is a strong probability that the eagles could accelerate to almost the speed of light.

And if the eagles had such advanced propulsion methods, I have to wonder why the people in Moonbased Alpha didn't simply use the eagles to return to Earth immediately after the Moon was blasted out of Earth orbit.

Comment: If you start trying to analyse it accurately, those kinds of velocities are going to cause some major relativistic effects that would have been visible over the course of the show.